# AQGridView: Could not call the cellForItemAtIndex method manually

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my iPAd app,

I am using AQGridView.

It has many cards.

On button click I am changing the array of Images.(Means replacing the images).

-Code for loading the cards with Image that I have written on below method.

```
- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
```

******Now that method is called twice occassions.**

**1. When first time it displays cell.(Allocating).**

**2.When you scroll the AQGridView.******

Here is a stack for that method..
[image]

Now When I am Manually calling

```
LayoutSubviews

OR

[self.gridView reloadData];
```

As, some parameters differ in this methods of AQGridView.

It is not working at all.Means could not call the method.

So, I am calling the method like, do you have any other solutions.

```
  for(int i=0;i<[toShowArray count];i++)
    {
    [self.gridView.dataSource gridView:self.gridView cellForItemAtIndex:i];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`[self.gridView reloadData];` should eventually invoke `cellForItemAtIndex` as long as you hooked up the data source like this:

```
self.gridView.dataSource = self;
```

But since you asked for other solutions, this should invoke `cellForItemAtIndex` for each element, too:

```
int dataElemCount = [toShowArray count];
NSIndexSet* indices = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, dataElemCount)];
[self.gridView beginUpdates];
[self.gridView reloadItemsAtIndices:indices withAnimation:AQGridViewItemAnimationFade];
[self.gridView endUpdates];
```

Note that `reloadItemsAtIndices` only works within `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. You can also change the animation to any other `AQGridViewItemAnimation` you like.